# 04 Ford mustang has no bass

Tags: ford, audio, mustang, speakers

I have a 2004 ford mustang and the radio sounds tinny although the sound is clear not distorted. I am trying to figure out if it is the radio or the speakers. I find it hard to believe all six speakers are bad. Any help?

Comment: I assume you've checked the bass and treble settings, or the equalizer if so equipped?

Comment: *It's all about the bass, 'bout the bass ... no treble.*

Comment: Since the funny business is out of the way ... to follow on with what @NateEldredge is asking ... what trouble shooting have you done?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably the terrible stock speakers. Upgrade your speakers or put in a subwoofer if you want bass.